# Combination of verb + ことも

Tags: particle-も

In the following sentence:

知りたい こと も、後で ちゃんと 教えてあげる…

The first part: 知りたい こと, I understand as: *what (you) want to know*, because of -tai and koto combination.

The second part: 後で ちゃんと 教えてあげる…, means I think: *(I) will properly inform (you) later*.

The above seems to make sense when put together, but I think I'm not capturing the meaning of も. The first part seems like a noun and with a single も in the sentence my guess would be *too/also*.

Considering this, could the sentence be translated as:
*(It is) what (I) want to know too, (I) will properly inform (you) later.*? Am I at least close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as I read your last sentence, I knew that you were overthinking.  The sentence in question is much simpler than you seem to think both in structure and meaning.

> 「知{し}りたい こと **も**、後{あと}で ちゃんと 教{おし}えてあげる。」

The 「も」 simply suggests that there are other things (besides what the listener wants to know) that the speaker will be explaining/teaching for the listener later on.

In other words, 「も」 modifies 「教えてあげる」.

Your guess of 「も」 being "too/also" is correct, but the important thing is to know "what too", "also what", etc.

Unless this sentence appeared in a context/situation ***so unusual*** that I could not even have imagined, it would mean:

> "I will surely teach (or "explain to") you the thing(s) you want(ed) to know ***and stuff (or "other things")***."